# Using the Web template in service fabric produces a non-managed ASP .NET5 project

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Working on a sample Service Fabric app. I created services and tested them. Now I wanted to add an API Gateway that acts as an entry point to my app...so in VS, I right-clicked on the services and chose the Web Template ASP.NET 5. It did create a regular ASP .NET 5...not managed by Service Fabric...there is no Package Root or Program.cs for example.

What am I doing wrong please? Of course, a regular ASP .NET 5 works ...but I wanted the whole app (including the gateway) to be managed by the Service Fabric.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

When you right-click to add in a service it is a common mistake to select the solution root (like you would normally do) to add in another project.  But, in order to add in a new fabric service (including ASP.NET 5), you have to right-click the main service fabric project (the one with the ApplicationManifest.xml) and then select Add => New Fabric Service. You will then get the dialog box where you can select ASP.NET 5 Web Api.

Right-click here first:

[image: Add]

Then select Add => New Fabric Service:

[image: New Fabric Service]

Comment: Great...thank you. That worked! Given this managed ASP .NET 5, how do I send logs to the Fabric's diagnostic events? I tied the ServiceEventSource that i see in all services, but it did not work.